# How can I tar multiple files in Perl?

Tags: perl, include, tar

How can I tar multiple directories and also append files with some pattern like '.txt' and exclude some directories and exclude some patterns like '.exe' all into a single tar file. The main point is the number of directories are unknown(dynamic), so I need to loop through I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have worked out what files you want using File::Find then something like

```
    my @dir = qw/a b/ ;
    system "tar -cvf mytar @dir" ;
```

might work. But you might find that the command line is too long.

In which case maybe write the list of files to a file and use the option

```
   --files-from=NAME
```

(and please don't tell me you are not allowed to write to files)

Comment: It will break if any of the file names include a character with special meaning for the shell. Provide arguments as the list after the PROGRAM argument.

Comment: presumably you are referring to my first suggstion.  The files in --file-from would be safe against that.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Tar) and populate `@filelist` with [Class::Path](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) (specifically `Class::Path::Dir`'s `recurse` method)

Comment: I cannot use Archive::Tar, because i am using system call to create a tar file(its the requirement)

$tarExe = "$toolDir/bin/gnu_tar/${binPlatform}/tar.exe";
system("${tarExe} -cvf $tarname $location");

Comment: You have a requirement to do it the hard way? There is no good reason to do that on a real project. Is this homework?

Comment: i need to use tar.exe from the winx64 folder to create the tar file.
This is standard method I was suggested to do. Its a real project to create tar files.

Comment: Using a Perl module is the standard way to do things in Perl, shelling out to other binaries is not.

Comment: If it was a suggestion, then you don't have to do it that way. Do it the right way instead.

Comment: Is there some requirement that no additional software be installed? If not, just install the module.

Comment: Archive::Tar comes with Perl (since 5.009003, according to corelist).

Comment: how do i make a system call to exclude some folders while TARring directories.   

i need to tar my1 and my2 from RandomName and myPacket as basetar.tar and exclude my3 from myPacket.
This is what i have and it doesnt work...any suggestion?.  

tar -cvf basetar.tar input\RandomName\my1 input\RandomName\my2 input\myPacket --exclude=input\myPacket\my3

Comment: If you have requirements that you cannot install modules, perhaps you could state this in the question so that if people spend (waste?) time answering you question ......

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot, or are not permitted to, install additional modules beyond the base system you could use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) instead of Class::Path.

It sounds like you already know how to call out to the system tar command so I'll leave it at that.