# How do i make a "system call to tar files(along with exclude tag)" to work in Perl

Tags: perl, command-line, tar

This is the system call, i am making right now in perl to tar the files

```
system("${tarexe} -pcvf $tarname $includepath") which works fine.

$tarexe -> location of my tar.exe file
$tarname -> myMock.tar
$includepath -> ./input/myMockPacketName ./input/myPacket/my2/*.wav ./input/myPacket/my3 ./input/myPacket/in.html
```

Now i want to exclude some files using exclude tag, which doesnot exclude the files

```
system("${tarexe} -pcvf $tarname $includepath --exclude $excludepath")

$excludepath -> ./input/myMockPacketName/my3
```

The same stament

```
${tarexe} -pcvf $tarname $includepath --exclude $excludepath
```

doesnot work when i run it in the command line.

Comment: So you mean `--exclude` isn't working?

Comment: it doesnot exclude the directories when i make a system call in perl along with --exclude tag(but it tars the included path)

Comment: This looks extremely similar to the question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545955/how-can-i-tar-multiple-files-in-perl

Comment: @justintime There i didnot know how to make a call(no exclude tag), now i did make the call(with exclude tag), but it doesnot work!! ....Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@superstar -

To asnwer your specific question, --exclude should probably be "./input/myMockPacketName/my3/*" instead of "./input/myMockPacketName/my3" from what I recall of GNU tar. Also, included file names are supposed to go after --exclude stuff; which should be quoted properly

**BUT**

Why are the requirements telling you HOW to do stuff as opposed to WHAT to do?

Unless it's homework (in which case please be upfront about it)

... or those are requirements from some company's generic architecture team (in which case they should be politely educated that industry standard best practices are to use Perl's native libraries over system calls whenever possible unless there's a clear reason to do otherwise) ...

in every other but those 2 cases you should decide on what method to use for implementation.

Comment: I tried this as well -> "./input/myMockPacketName/my3/*"
but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you try to switch exclude and include places?

Comment: Also, did you try to redirect output/error into a file and seeing what gets printed?

Comment: @DVK: i tried switching places of include and exclude places(in vain).
I do not think i am getting an error, the command tars the included paths well, without excluding the excluded paths. is this what you meant? if not, can you be more elaborative. thanks!

Comment: I meant that there may have been some *warning* in the output from tar that didn't halt the tarring yet complained somehow about some issue with excludes.

Comment: Also, could you please try putting in ABSOLUTE path for excludes just to eliminate relative path as a possible culprit? It's unlikely but let's limit the # of moving pieces

Comment: @DVK there are no warnings or errors and i tried absolute and relative paths(result negative).

Comment: Is there ANY difference in output from the command running via Perl and the command running from the OS?

Comment: @DVK: none at all. It includes the given paths(without excluding the exclude path) by call from Perl and thats it !

Comment: Do me a favor. Create a batch file that calls the tar command. Run that batch file from windows and separately from perl. See if it gets better

Comment: sorry for the confusion!! I was actually using the wrong tar. Now i realised i need to use gnu_tar and when i use this the --exclude doesnot work for commandline as well!!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't a clue to why your `--exclude` isn't working. But I'll give you my favourite perl advice when I see a `system` in use.

**Don't**

Of course sometimes they are necessary but check first if there is a CPAN module to do the job instead. In this case I suggest [Archive::TarGzip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::TarGzip) normally I would use [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Tar) but I could not find `--exclude` functionality *(I only had a quick look so it may be there)*

Comment: Thank you for responding to me. I had --exclude tag working when i type the same command in command line. But it doesnot work when i call the same thing from the system call in perl. (I need to make a system call here, because i need to use my tar.exe, according to the requirements).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to the question but a hint that might help you pin down problems like this in the future:

Rather than write

```
system("${tarexe} -pcvf $tarname $includepath --exclude $excludepath")
```

do something like

```
my $command = "${tarexe} -pcvf $tarname $includepath --exclude $excludepath"  ;

print "About to run $command\n" ;
system $command ;
```

You can then  cut and paste the output getnerated into a new terminal window. Or you may spot that the command generated isnt what you thought it was.

**Disclaimer** - I agree with most people that have ansewred this question that using Perl Tar modules would be better, but accept there may be reasons for doing it this way

Comment: Thanks for the wise suggestion. I tried it and the $command is what I expect (the same command i ran in command line) but the output does not exclude the directories. Do you think these commands are machine specific?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is to do with TAR rather than Perl.  You could try "tar --help" .  You could try with a simpler test case from command line.

Comment: its the problem with system call from Perl, because the same command excludes the paths(with --exclude) in command line. But now from Perl(system call), it tars the include paths well, but doesnot exclude the excluded paths.